# Is it posible to implement functions that use non blocking setTimeout synchronically?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, iif

I wonder if it is possible to call these 2 IIF synchronically that they produce at the end something like that?

```
######
#####
####
###
##
#
#
##
###
####
#####
###### ?
```

the functions below do delayed console log. The idea is to console log with some delay row by row.

```
 (function whileLoop(n) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let hashArr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => {
                return hashSymbol
            });
            console.log(hashArr);
            if (--n) whileLoop(n);
        }, 2000)
    })(6);

    (function whileLoop(n, m) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let hashArr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => {
                return hashSymbol
            });
            console.log(hashArr);
            if (n < m) {
                ++n;
                whileLoop(n, m);
            }
        }, 2000)
    })(1, 6);
```

Comment: you mean one after the other?

Comment: there are lots of ways to do what you want but basically you have two options:

1. use a promise or some implementation with a callback function to invoke the second function after the first one completes.

2. use a variable in both functions' scopes to set a start condition for the second function.

Without more specific information about your constraints, its hard to be more exact.

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to display it one by one, you need to use `async` `await`.
 Please check here: https://javascript.info/async-await

```js
 const row = 6;
    (async() => {
   for (let r = 1;r < row * 2; r++) {
     await displayAsync('#'.repeat((r >= 7 ? (r % 6) : row - r ) + 1));
   }
})();

function displayAsync(str) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=> {
       console.log(str);
       resolve(null); 
      }, 1000);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to handle the order of execution for two different asynchronous operations would be to use promises.

```js
var d = $.Deferred();

(function whileLoop(n) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let hashArr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => {
      return '#'
    });
    console.log(hashArr);
    if (--n) whileLoop(n);
    else d.resolve();
  }, 2000)
})(6);

d.then(function() {
  (function whileLoop(n, m) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      let hashArr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(() => {
        return '#'
      });
      console.log(hashArr);
      if (n < m) {
        ++n;
        whileLoop(n, m);
      }
    }, 2000)
  })(1, 6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. I see that you understand that the recursive call to `setTimeout` emulates a while loop asynchronously. And I see that you understand how to decide when to continue the "loop" and when to stop:

```
if (--n) whileLoop(n);
```

You just need to realize that the loop ends when the `if` condition is false. Thus, to run the second while loop just start it in the `else`:

```
if (--n) {
    whileLoop(n);
}
else {
    whileLoop2(1,6);
}
```

There's a few repercussions of this:

1. The second `whileLoop` must be re-written to **NOT** be an IIFE - it must be a regular function called at the end of the first `whileLoop` as above.
2. You cannot reuse the name `whileLoop` for both functions. To differentiate the functions you must rename either the first or second "loop" functions.

This preserves your current logic requiring only 4 lines to be changed to get the behavior you want.